# I cannot figure out why my output is being printed twice

Tags: python, printing, output

I have a script that has 2 functions. The first function calculates the factorial of a number passed into it, the second function takes an integer and prints out all of the factorials up to that number. It is calculating the factorials correctly and printing the set correctly but it prints the set twice which has me confused.

Here is the code I have and I want it to print just 1 - 362880 once but it prints twice as shown below. Also the "None" in there does not make sense to me. Any ideas on this?

Code:

```
#calculate factorial of a number
def factorial(n):
    #initialize and assign product to be returned to the print function
    product = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        product = product * i
    return product

#print factorials up to 1 less than given argument
def print_factorial(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(factorial(i))

print_factorial(10)
```

Result:
1
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
1
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
None

Comment: tried your code and it worked fine, it didn't print twice

Comment: Ok thank you, it might be something with the coursera quiz interpreter acting funky

Answer (score 0):

Both `factorial(0)` and `factorial(1)` returns `1`, so `1` will be printed twice.